# Use variables in here-string

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, here-string

To feed input to an interactive script, I've been using a here-string:

```
script <<< $'1 2\n3 4\n5 6\nq'
```

This effectively enters

```
1 2
3 4
5 6
q
```

into the script. But how can I replace one of these with a variable?

```
script <<< $'$var 2\n3 4\n...'
```

does not work...

Comment: have you tried double quote (`"`) ?

Comment: I tried, and it does not seem to work.

Comment: just in case `echo "$var 2\n3 4\n..." | script ` ?

Comment: Not working either, but `echo "1 2\n3 4\n..." | script` is also not working properly, so...

Comment: `man echo` (or `man bash` and search for `echo`) → `echo -e`

Comment: Why aren't you using a heredoc and avoid those problems ?

Answer (score 9):

That's not the here string, it's [ANSI-C quoting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting):

> Words of the form $'string' are treated specially. ... The expanded result is single-quoted, as if the dollar sign had not been present.

So what you've got is a single-quoted string to the right of `<<<`. That string gets taken as the here string, with no further processing.

There's no need to use only a single set of quotes around the whole word, however. You can use several quoted parts (or unquoted single words) joined together:

```
script <<< "$var 2"$'\n'"3 4"$'\n'"5 6"$'\n'q
```

will do what you wanted.

Alternatively, you could backslash-escape the spaces, rather than quoting `"1 2"`.

---

You could also use [`echo -e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-echo----------) with a regular pipe:

```
echo -e "$var 2\n3 4\n5 6\nq" | script
```

or [`printf`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-printf):

```
printf '%s 2\n3 4\nq' "$var" | script
```

`-e` is necessary to enable escape processing in `echo`'s arguments. `printf` does those by default, but it has its own interpolation system (`printf "$var 2\n3 4\nq"` will also work, but is problematic if `$var` might contain escape characters).

Answer (score 1):

The `$'...'` ANSI-C quoting results in a "single-quoted" string.
Inside a single quoted string variables are not expanded:

```
$ var=13

$ echo 'test $var'
test $var
```

You need to take the variable out of such structure. The easiest way IMO is:

```
$  printf -v val '%s 2\n3 4\n5 6\nq' "$var"
13 2
3 4
5 6
q
```

The format to `printf` is very similar to what you had before, and the `%s` is replaced by the value of the variable. To get the result in a variable, we can use the capacity of bash printf of setting a variable:

```
$ printf -v val '%s 2\n3 4\n5 6\nq' "$var"
$ script <<< "$val"
```

All in one line:

```
$ printf -v val '%s 2\n3 4\n5 6\nq' "$var"; script <<< "$val"
```